# Motorola MC40 doesn't recognize cyrillic symbols at DataMatrix code

Tags: android, barcode, motorola, cyrillic

I'm using Motorola MC40 on android with EMDK. When I scan Data Matrix code with cyrillic symbols like capital "О" (U041E), function ScanData.getData() is returning String with character "�" (code 65533).

When I use software tool i-nigma sdk, it return string of charracters in 1251 codepage and I can recognize it.

Could anyone help me read my DataMatrix barcodes with EMDK?

Image:

[image: DataMatrix Barcode for string: #1@#ОС@#0700022520]

coded string: #1@#ОС@#0700022520

i-nigma decoded sequence of bytes hex:
[23 31 40 23 ce d1 40 23 30 37 30 30 30 32 32 35 32 30]

mc40 decoded string: #1@#��@#0700022520

EMDK version: 3.1
OS Version: 4.1.1

As far as I understand I need get sequence of read bytes before they are converted to string, or set code page of source data for the converter.

Comment: Can you make available an image of barcode? which version of EMDK are you using and which OS version on the MC40?

Comment: I added a image and the software versions

Comment: I see the issue you reported, I'm trying to understand if there's any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra's EMDK v4.0 released January 2016 introduce a new method in the Barcode API to scan Raw data: [`getRawData()`](http://zebra.github.io/emdk-for-android/4-0/api/barcode/ScanDataCollection-ScanData/#getRawData).

As an example you can use the following code in the [BarcodeSample1 you can find on github](https://github.com/developer-zebra/samples-emdkforandroid-4_0/blob/BarcodeSample1/app/src/main/java/com/symbol/barcodesample1/MainActivity.java)

```
@Override public void onData(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection) {

if ((scanDataCollection != null) &&
    (scanDataCollection.getResult() == ScannerResults.SUCCESS)) {

  ArrayList <ScanData> scanData = scanDataCollection.getScanData();
  for(ScanData data : scanData) {
      //Barcode label type
      String dataString = "Label Type: " + data.getLabelType() + "\n" ;
      //Barcode data as encoded String
      dataString += "Encoded Data Size: " + data.getData().length() +
                    " String: " + data.getData() + "\n";
      //Barcode data as Raw Data
      dataString += "Raw Data Size: " + data.getRawData().length + 
                    " (Hex): " + bytesToHexString(data.getRawData());

      new AsyncDataUpdate().execute(dataString);
    }
  } 
}
```

where `bytesToHexString()` is a simple helper function:

```
    public static String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes){ 

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for(byte b : bytes){
        sb.append(String.format("%02x ", b&0xff));
        }
    return sb.toString();   
}
```

In this case `getRawData` returns a `byte[]` containing barcode's raw data.

Answer (score 0):

On the newer Zebra Technologies devices based on Android KitKat, the Scanning Framework allows to specify the character set.

In a DataWedge Profile you can specify in the `Reader Params` which one you want to use:

- `UTF-8` (default)
- `Shift JIS`
- `ISO-8859-1`

This option is currently not available on the MC40.

Comment: This is so strange. Why not just give access to the raw bytes of the scanned data?

Comment: Raw data access is currently in beta testing.

Comment: When you are planning to release an update?
Can I take part in the beta testing?